# Taxes and Minecraft servers

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business

I am a teenager who plans to start a Minecraft server. I live in the United States and I assume that I will need to pay taxes.

My parents want to find out more about the taxes. I've read a couple of things but I'm not sure what to do. Obviously I want to pay as little as possible.  How do I do this? Also what kind of taxes does the server count as?

Comment: You'll only pay taxes on profit, are Minecraft servers profitable?

Comment: Another similar question: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/87608/10997